# Facebook FB.api('/me/accounts') is not returning list of applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I have been written a code that retrieves users page list and application list so I can make a page tab connector. And I used FB.api(/me/accounts) for this purpose. It was several months ago and it worked well.

https://www.facebook.com/WEBLAB54/app_337216453020586

But suddenly, Facebook api will show me only a list of pages, not a list of applications. I have tried to find solution online, but it seems that nobody has this problem? Also I went to facebook page for manage_pages permission, and there is no changes in documentation.

Does anybody know what is the problem?

I will put a PHP code just in case, but this code worked fine until few days ago.

```
function get_user_applications(){
    $accounts_data =  $this->facebook->api('/me/accounts');
    $accounts_data = $accounts_data["data"];
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($accounts_data);$i++){
        if($accounts_data[$i]['category'] == "Application")
            $users_apps[]=$accounts_data[$i];
    }
    return  $users_apps;    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep up to date with Facebook :-)

This change was announced back in December, and is effective as of March 6th:

> Removing apps from /me/accounts/
>
> We will no longer show apps under /me/accounts/ in the Graph API. You can access the list of apps a user is a developer on by hitting /me/applications/developer/.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: Plus, the pages those access tokens were for managing were wer emoved over a year ago, so there was no reason to use those access tokens

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't noticed that update (actually I did not followed at all), but this will be my practice from now on. It works very well! :)

Answer (score 1):

In response by default we will get only 25 pages and you have to call api like below to get all the pages

```
me/accounts/?type=pages&limit=200
```

Here 200 is an assumption, but you have to specify the limit in order to get more than 25.